# How do you make a banner clickable in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, branding, suitebar

I'm using SharePoint 2016 and I added a logo/banner to the Suite Bar.  How can I make this region clickable and forward to a webpage?  I don't see a way to do this in css using .o365cs-base.  Do I need to reference the image in .o365cs-base and add href to the html or master page?

I created a css file, uploaded to SiteAssets and added it to Alternate CSS URL under Site Settings - Look and Feel - Master Page.

Here is the css I used to add the logo:

.o365cs-base.o365cs-topnavBGColor-2
{
background-color: #101E8E !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url('banner.png') !Important;
background-position: 50px;
width: auto;
height: 65px;
}

Comment: How you have added a logo/banner to the suite bar? can you please add the steps you used or the code you used (if any) to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added jquery the the html file and referenced the class in the alternate css file.

https://api.jquery.com/wrap/